# Python not finding torch

Tags: python, pytorch, python-module

I want to use [deepsaber](https://github.com/oxai/deepsaber).
For that I have to Install Torch.

I did this using `pip install torch torchvision`.

After running `cd scripts/generation` and `./script_generate.sh [path to song]` python tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_stage1.py", line 16, in <module>
    from models import create_model
  File "/home/server/deepsaber/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base_model import BaseModel
  File "/home/server/deepsaber/models/base_model.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_stage2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from models import create_model
  File "/home/server/deepsaber/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base_model import BaseModel
  File "/home/server/deepsaber/models/base_model.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

using `import torch` works like a charm when using `python`

any ideas of what I can do?

The repos says:

> pytorch (installed as torch or via https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you installed `torch` using Python 2, while `script_generate.sh` uses Python 3 (see [here](https://github.com/oxai/deepsaber/blob/356b43bf5db256da4adf4a19cc9aa5bf1c115be9/scripts/generation/script_generate.sh#L23)):

```sh
# [...]
py=python3
# [...]
```

Try to run `pip3 install torch torchvision` or `python3 -m pip install torch torchvision`. Also, check if `import torch` works when using `python3`.